# JQuery slideToggle acting up

Tags: jquery, hover, slidetoggle, hoverintent

I am having trouble with this set up. When I click the 'Services' link it drops down, but then if I use the same 'Services' link to close the drop down/slide down area, when I reopen it, it doesn't expand/contract to fit the content, the size just freezes, where as if I close it with the 'Close' link that's inside the slide down area, it carries on working fine.

(Click Services, Hover over a link, then click Services again to close it, then again to open it and hover over a link again to show the problem I mean)

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9zK29/2/) for reference

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#closebtn").click(function(){
            $(".expandable").stop().slideUp().delay(600);
            $(".expandable2").stop().slideUp().delay(600);
            $("#taglinecontainer").stop().slideToggle({queue: false}).delay(600);
        });
        $("#toggleservices").click(function(){
            $(".expandable").slideUp().delay(600);
            $("#fullservices").stop().slideToggle({queue: false});
            $("#taglinecontainer").stop().slideToggle({}).delay(600);
        });
        $("#togglesectors").click(function(){
            $(".expandable").slideUp().delay(600);
            $("#fullsectors").slideToggle({queue: false});
            $("#taglinecontainer").slideToggle({}).delay(600);
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#togglestrategyblurb").hoverIntent(function(){
            $(".expandable2").slideUp();
            $("#strategyblurb").slideToggle();
        }, function(){
        });
        $("#toggledesignblurb").hoverIntent(function(){
            $(".expandable2").slideUp();
            $("#designblurb").slideToggle();
        }, function(){
        });
        $("#toggleprblurb").hoverIntent(function(){
            $(".expandable2").slideUp();
            $("#prblurb").slideToggle();
        }, function(){
        });
        $("#togglewebblurb").hoverIntent(function(){
            $(".expandable2").slideUp();
            $("#webblurb").slideToggle();
        }, function(){
        });
    });
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. You probably just have a logic error somewhere.

Comment: I could only reproduce the glitch in IE9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this solves your issue: [Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/9zK29/3/)

```
 $("#toggleservices").click(function(){

    $("#fullservices").stop().slideToggle({queue: false});
    $("#taglinecontainer").stop().slideToggle({}).delay(600);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

add `overflow` to your `header`

```
header {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    min-height: 50px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```